# GRUB2 Chainload

Tags: boot, grub2, grub-efi, secure-boot

I want to add to the `GRUB` configutation file (.cfg) menuentries for the `MokManager` and variuos custom `GRUB` generated with `grub-mkstandalone`.

I've tried the chainload process before editing the file, but I haven't succeeded.

`Secure Boot` is enabled.

Code:

```
insmod chain
chainloader ([EFI PARTITION])/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
boot
```

Output:

```
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(*)/PCI(*)/Sata(*)/HD(*)/
           File(\EFI\ubuntu)/File(MokManager.efi)/EndEntire
error: Cannot load image
```

The same happens for any others bootloaders.

**UPDATE:**

I've read that this behaviour is caused by a `GRUB2` bug, which can't launch other bootloaders when `Secure Boot` is enabled, because `GRUB` actually hasn't the cryptos to verify the signs unlike `shim`.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464

For the `OpenSUSE GRUB`, *Michael Chang* came out with a patch on 2012 that make `GRUB` rely on shim verification to chainload other binaries:

https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory/grub2/grub2-secureboot-chainloader.patch

Comment: What was the error?  The "cannot load path"  is the grub bug.  If "cannot find path" that's something else.

Comment: @ubfan1 Actually I think it's the bug related to the Secure Boot, because when it's disabled it works fine. Please, read the update and view the links...

Comment: What if you use *openSUSE* as the main operating system and use its grub also the boot Ubuntu? You can try to install the grub bootloader from/for openSUSE, and then run `sudo update-grub` in openSUSE. It should find Ubuntu and create a grub menuentry for it. - That way you can avoid chainloading.

Comment: @sudodus Yeah, I think it should work, but it's definitely not the right thing to sugggest in general: install an OS only for a specific packet or a specific configuration, even if it's the bootloader. The `OpenSUSE GRUB` sources can always be compiled, but I think it's better that someone patches the `Ubuntu GRUB`, to make it available to all users, with a .deb package too.

Comment: That is a good idea. *I suggest that you create a bug report* about it at Launchpad, http://launchpad.net/ - that is the way to communicate with the developers.

Comment: @sudodus Have you seen the link I provided? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464 This seem to me more a choice of not to patch this bug.

Comment: I don't know. It seems that Ubuntu works with Windows with secure boot in some computers, but not in some other computers. You can add some heat to the bug report by clicking that you are affected too, and write a detailed comment about your particular case - if you are sure it is the same bug. Otherwise it it better to create a new bug report (with reference to that old report to give people a chance to merge the bug reports, if it *is* the same bug).

Comment: @sudodus I don't think this depends on the machine. `GRUB` doesn't have cryptos in its binary unlike `shim` and if you get the sources take a look at `grub-core/loader/efi/chainloader.c`, you can see the chainloading process lacks of the `Secure Boot` support.

Comment: Should the title be:***Grub can't boot in secure mode*** instead? Is it only EFI that can't secure boot or CSM as well?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix `CSM` has not such thing as `Secure Boot`, and beside that,  my `GRUB`  can boot with `Secure Boot` enabled, but it cannot chainload other binaries.

Comment: @JumpAlways I must confess I've never enabled secure boot or administrative BIOS password on my laptop, nor UEFI for that matter. Should the title be ***How do I make GRUB chainload with secure boot enabled?*** . That will keep people like me from opening the question :)

Answer (score 1):

### The 40_custom method

Some pendrives boot from grub even if they won't boot from the computer's own BIOS USB boot menu entry. See the following link for a background about grub

[Scripts: /etc/grub.d/](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Scripts:_.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-grub.d.2BAC8-)

Edit the file

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Add the following text to the file 40_custom (notice that it is important to keep the first lines, that come with the file)

```
menuentry "External drive (on hd1) if no eSATA drive connected. edit if necessary" {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        set root='(hd1)'
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}
```

and run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then you will get a grub menu option to boot from a second drive (hd1), which could be a USB pendrive. If another drive is hd1, you can edit the line to (hd2) etc.

If there is no grub menu, press the left shift key during boot, and it should appear.

---

I use this chainloading method in BIOS mode. I have not tested it in UEFI mode.

Comment: I want to load different version of GRUB inside the same disk

Comment: I see. I have not done that.

Comment: Actually this behaviour doesn't depend on the location of the other binaries or if they are in the same one of the main bootloader.